# JQuery - enable/disable checkboxs per row

Tags: jquery

I have a query that returns a table list of available services and each table row of returned services has 3 checkboxes- Book, Send Info, No Thanks.

```
echo '<td align="center">'.'<input type="checkbox" id="ckBook_'.$i.'"  name="ckBook['.$i.']"></input>'.'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.'<input type="checkbox"  id="ckSendInfo_'.$i.'" name="ckSendInfo['.$i.']" class="group1_'.$i.'"></input>'.'</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'.'<input type="checkbox" id="ckNoThanks_"  name="ckNoThanks['.$i.']" class="group1_'.$i.'"></input>'.'</td>';
```

If a user clicks on one of the checkboxes in one of the rows, then the other checkboxes on the same row should be disabled, else they should be enabled.  I've tried using radio buttons, but the Book checkbox is also returning a running total at the bottom and when I use radio buttons it messes up the totaling function.

I've researched and think I'm pretty close to the solution. I modified some code I found on this site, but it currently only affects the second and third column when the first column check box (of any row) is selected.

```
$(function() {
 enable_cb();
 $('input[id^=ckBook_]').click(enable_cb);
 $('input[id^=ckSendInfo_]').click(enable_cb);
 $('input[id^=ckNoThanks_]').click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
 if (this.checked) 
  {
     $("input.group1_0").attr("disabled", true);
  }   

 else
   {
    $("input.group1_0").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("input.group1_1").removeAttr("disabled");
  }

}
```

Comment: Note: input tags are auto-closing tags, you should write them `<input />` and not `<input></input>`

Answer (score 2):

This simple code will do it:

```
// bind a click handler on any of those checkboxes
// withint the table #tableID
$('input[type=checkbox]', '#tableID').click(function(e) {

    // 'this' is the clicked checkbox
    $(this).closest('tr')
        // go to the TR parent and find all checkboxes,
        // but exclude myself with .not()
        .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
        // use .prop() to set special attributes like disabled
        .prop('disabled', this.checked);

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/RrTH9/)**

Further reading:

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: +1 for the answer I would've done if I'd read the question properly. (I've deleted my answer.)

Comment: I have added some comments and a context to limit the bind of the click event to the checkboxes within the table with ID "#tableID" (change with your table ID).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function enable_cb() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
         $("input.group1_0").attr("disabled", true);
      }else{
        $("input.group1_0").attr("disabled", false);
        $("input.group1_1").attr("disabled", false);
      }  
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
   var elems = $(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox');
   elems.not($(this)).attr('disabled',$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the try! However it produces the same affect as before - any Book checkbox (Send Info or No Thanks) that is checked then disables only the top row of Send Info and No Thanks. I actually need this to be exclusive to each row that is returned.